# why cout is giving different values

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int sum,a,b;
    a=4;
    b=4;
    sum=a+b;
    cout<<sum;
    cout<<sum;

}
```

Q1 Why cout is not executing twice?
Q2 why 2nd cout is giving different value?

Comment: Show the output you got.:)

Comment: You may want to add a space or newline between your `cout` lines.

Answer (score 5):

> Why cout is not executing twice?

It is executing twice.

> why 2nd cout is giving different value?

Both outputs are 8.

If that's not the case for you, then there may be something wrong with your compiler, your computer, the operating system, or maybe you are running a different program.

Comment: You forgot to mention another possible reason for the difference in output - matrix malfunction.

Comment: @SergeyA *Glitch in the matrix

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius that's what you get when you attempt to translate back to original :D Thanks.

Comment: ... or the prompt of the shell overwrites some or all of what the program wrote.